# Count type of values of each column

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to get some type function in Pandas that would help me find how many strings and ints are there per column.

Example:

```
    A    B    C    D

    1    H    3    20
    3    5    2    1
    2    Y         M
```

Should give me something  like

```
    A    B    C    D

int 3    1    2    2
str 0    2    0    1
NA  0    0    1    0
```

Any function that does so? I was thinking of making up something like: if (A==int'A') then ..., and use a counter, but I guess it would go element by element and would be super inefficient.

Comment: @DyZ Sure you can.  `dtype` of the column must be `object` and it can contain any number of `types`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 3, 2],
    B=['H', 5, 'Y'],
    C=[3, 2, None],
    D=[20, 1, 'M']
), dtype=object)

df

   A  B     C   D
0  1  H     3  20
1  3  5     2   1
2  2  Y  None   M
```

---

**Solution**
Use `pd.DataFrame.applymap` with `type` and `pd.value_counts`

```
df.applymap(type).apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

                    A  B  C  D
<class 'int'>       3  1  2  2
<class 'str'>       0  2  0  1
<class 'NoneType'>  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I'll test it and come back!